# Javascript - sort colors based on visible difference

Tags: javascript, sorting, colors

I have an array of RGB values:

```
var arr = [[255, 255, 255], [100, 100, 100], [255, 0, 0], etc...]
```

I am wanting to arrange my RGB values based on visible difference using the `CIEDE2000` that is a part of https://github.com/markusn/color-diff so that similar colors are close together.

What I have been doing so far is converting all RGB values to LAB, then creating a second array of arrays. Each value is `[i, difference]` where `i` represents the original place in the first array that the `difference` value refers to. And the `difference` value is the difference as calculated by `CIEDE2000` between that specific color in the original array and black.

Then I sort the second array by ascending difference. The problem is that this doesn't result in the sorted array I'm looking for.

Imagine the following scenario:

Original Colors: `[[dark blue], [orange], [light blue], [slightly brighter orange]]` (I'm not writing RGB values for clarity sake.)

That will be sorted into `[[dark blue], [orange], [slightly lighter orange], [light blue]]`

The problem is that the blues are split up. They are split up because dark blue is actually the closest visually to black and light blue is the farthest. Even though they are far away from orange, they are of differing amounts away from black.

So how can I sort my original colour array to return a properly sorted array?

The above should be sorted as:

`[[dark blue], [light blue], [orange], [slightly lighter orange]]`

Although it doesn't matter if the blues are before or after the oranges. As long as they are all together. In a real scenario I would have thousands of different colors.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems a bit doomed; RGB is a three-dimensional value, so the right way to sort into a linear order seems ambiguous. Are you open to other approaches?

Comment: So do you have a formula to calc the difference or to give some sort of "value" for the color?

Comment: The function from `color-diff` simply takes two LAB values and outputs a difference value from 1 to 100. 1 being visually the same. 100 being visually opposite.

Comment: Sure, that would give you a linear value, but a spectrum of difference magnitudes won't give you colors of a similar hue. Plus you'd have to choose an arbitrary starting point.

Answer (score 4):

If you are open to other approaches, try converting the color to HSL instead. The nice thing about HSL is it gives you a linear "hue" value which you could sort by instead. That should ensure you have similar colors next to each other. The tricky thing now would be on how to order saturation and luminosity within the same hue, but sorting in this order would probably look ok:

1. Hue (ascending, descending, doesn't matter)
2. Saturation
3. Luminosity

If you can't decide whether closeness in saturation or luminosity is more important than closeness in hue, then you're stuck with the same problem as RGB; ordering is ambiguous within a three-dimensional space. But HSL is more sane than RGB for perceived "closeness" of values.

Comment: That's interesting - I'll give it a shot and report back. Thanks!